Upload file on AWS S3 from Mall Plugin October CMS
I need to upload on AWS S3 the image product from Mall Plugin by October CMS
i've set cms.php with
'default' => 's3',
my filesystem.php
'default' => 's3',

  

      /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Filesystem Disks
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | Here you may configure as many filesystem "disks" as you wish, and you
        | may even configure multiple disks of the same driver. Defaults have
        | been setup for each driver as an example of the required options.
        |
        | Supported Drivers: "local", "ftp", "sftp", "s3"
        |
        */
    
        'disks' => [
    
            'local' => [
                'driver' => 'local',
                'root' => storage_path('app'),
                'throw' => false,
            ],
    
            'uploads' => [
                'driver' => 's3',
                'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
                'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
                'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
                'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
                'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
                'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
                'use_path_style_endpoint' => env('AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT', false),
                'throw' => false,
            ],
    
            'media' => [
                'driver' => 's3',
                'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
                'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
                'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
                'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
                'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
                'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
                'use_path_style_endpoint' => env('AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT', false),
                'throw' => false,
            ],
            
            'resources' => [
                'driver' => 'local',
                'root' => storage_path('app/resources'),
                'url' => '/storage/app/resources',
                'visibility' => 'public',
                'throw' => false,
            ],
    
            's3' => [
                'driver' => 's3',
                'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
                'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
                'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
                'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
                'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
                'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
                'use_path_style_endpoint' => env('AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT', false),
                'visibility' => 'public',
                'throw' => false,
            ]        
    
        ],

my policy on AWS bucket:
 "Version": "2008-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": "*",
                "Action": "s3:*",
                "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MYBUCKET/*"
            }
        ]

So, i don't know how when i upload the image about Mall Plugin there is no upload on AWS S3, but still use fileupload.js
How to set Mall Plugin to use S3?
Thanks

The issue is not with Mall plugin, if plugin upload images to uploads folder while storage is set to local, then it must work when storage is set to s3.
You must check following things.
=> Confirm ocotber Driver Plugin must installed.
=> If in aws bucket uploads & media directory not exist create and make them public
I am using Ocotber CMS 2.0 and here you need to modify two files.

system.php
filesystems.php

How system.php should look:
// [your_aws_path] = exampledomain.com.s3.amazonaws.com
'storage' => [

  'uploads' => [
    'disk'   => 's3',
    'folder' => 'uploads',
    'path'   => '[your_aws_path]/uploads',
  ],

'media' => [
    'disk'   => 's3',
    'folder' => 'media',
    //'path'   => '/storage/app/media',
    'path'   => '[your_aws_path]/media',
 ],

 'resources' => [
    'disk'   => 's3',
    'folder' => 'resources',
    //'path'   => '/storage/app/resources',
    'path'   => '[your_aws_path]/resources',
  ],

],

How filesystems.php should look:
set 'default' => 's3'
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
        'url' => '/storage/app',
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => [AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID],
        'secret' => [AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY],
        'region' => [AWS_DEFAULT_REGION],
        'bucket' => , [AWS_BUCKET]
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    'rackspace' => [
        'driver' => 'rackspace',
        'username' => 'your-username',
        'key' => 'your-key',
        'container' => 'your-container',
        'endpoint' => 'https://identity.api.rackspacecloud.com/v2.0/',
        'region' => 'IAD',
    ],

],

